# css image left not working

Tags: html, css

I do not know why my left is not working on image.
it's not working if i try with `#new_index_body_slide_image_2`, nor with `#new_index_body_slide_image_2 img`

**Here is my code:**

```css
#index_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
}
#new_index_body_slide_image_2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px; //not working
}
```

```html
<div id="body" style="height:600px">
  <div id="index_content">
    <div id="index_content_slide">
      <div id="new_index_body_slide_image_1">
        <img src="images/content_img/kuca2.jpg">
      </div>
      <div id="new_index_body_slide_image_2">
        <img src="images/content_img/new_gips.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="test()">Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No repro. It's "working" just fine with the shared code. https://jsfiddle.net/4wgLnm5f/

Comment: Same here, it's ok https://jsfiddle.net/ec6qt026/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working absolutely fine. By default `div`'s will be rendered as **block**, so the second image will be positioned on the next line and **30px** away from the left.

**Explanation for the issue:**

```css
#index_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
}
#new_index_body_slide_image_2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px; //not working
}
img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="body" style="height:600px">
  <div id="index_content">
    <div id="index_content_slide">
      <div id="new_index_body_slide_image_1">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8MqehqH.png">
      </div>
      <div id="new_index_body_slide_image_2">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pNgIqxQ.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="test()">Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In case you wish to position the images next to each other(on the same row). Try `top: 0` on the second image.

**Positioning image side by side:**

```css
#index_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
}
#new_index_body_slide_image_2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30px;
  /* not working */
}
img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="body" style="height:600px">
  <div id="index_content">
    <div id="index_content_slide">
      <div id="new_index_body_slide_image_1">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8MqehqH.png">
      </div>
      <div id="new_index_body_slide_image_2">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pNgIqxQ.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="test()">Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to `position:relative`